# Pandas column aggregation for duplicate values using custom function

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I have a dataframe and I want to aggregate the similar ids in column.

```
X_train['freq_qd1'] = X_train.groupby('qid1')['qid1'].transform('count')

X_train['freq_qd2'] = X_train.groupby('qid2')['qid2'].transform('count')
```

The above code I understand but i want to custom build a function to apply on multiple columns.
[image]

I have attached a snapshot of the dataframe for reference. On this dataframe i tried to apply a custom function on qid1 and qid2.
I tried the below code :

```
def frequency(qid):
        freq = []
        for i in str(qid):
            if i not in freq:
                freq.append(i)
                ids = set()
            if i not in ids:
                ids.add(i)
                freq.append(ids)
        return freq


def extract_simple_feat(fe) :
    fe['question1'] = fe['question1'].fillna(' ')
    fe['question2'] = fe['question2'].fillna(' ')
    fe['qid1'] = fe['qid1']
    fe['qid2'] = fe['qid2']

    token_feat = fe.apply(lambda x : get_simple_features(x['question1'], 
                          x['question2']), axis = 1)

fe['q1_len'] = list(map(lambda x : x[0], token_feat))
fe['q2_len'] = list(map(lambda x : x[1], token_feat))
fe['freq_qd1'] = fe.apply(lambda x: frequency(x['qid1']), axis = 1)
fe['freq_qd2'] = fe.apply(lambda x: frequency(x['qid2']), axis = 1)
fe['q1_n_words'] = list(map(lambda x : x[2], token_feat))
fe['q2_n_words'] = list(map(lambda x : x[3], token_feat))
fe['word_common'] = list(map(lambda x : x[4], token_feat))
fe['word_total'] = list(map(lambda x : x[5], token_feat))
fe['word_share'] = list(map(lambda x : x[6], token_feat))

return fe


X_train = extract_simple_feat(X_train)
```

after applying my own implementation i am not getting the desired result. i am attaching a snapshot for the result i got.
[image]

The desired result wanted is below:
[image]

if someone can help me because i am really stuck and not able to rectify it properly.

here's a small text input :

```
qid1     qid2 
  23       24
  25       26
  27       28
  318830   318831
  359558   318831
  384105   318831
  413505   318831
  451953   318831
  530151   318831
```

I want aggregation output as :

```
qid1      qid2    freq_qid1  freq_id2
 23        24        1          1
 25        26        1          1
 27        28        1          1
 318830    318831    1          6
 359558              1          6
 384105              1          6
 413505              1          6
 451953              1          6
 530151              1          6
```

Comment: Can you share the input data as text and not as an image?

Comment: are you talking about the data used for the problem because it is a comma separated file? @ medium-dimensional

Comment: Yes! Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more details.

Comment: I tried to provide a gist of the input data as there are lot of columns. @ medium-dimensional

Answer (score 0):

Given: (I added an extra row for an edge case)

```
     qid1    qid2
0      23      24
1      25      26
2      27      28
3  318830  318831
4  359558  318831
5  384105  318831
6  413505  318831
7  451953  318831
8  530151  318831
9  495894    4394
```

Doing:

```
def get_freqs(df, cols):
    temp_df = df.copy()
    for col in cols:
        temp_df['freq_' + col] = temp_df.groupby(col)[col].transform('count')
        temp_df.loc[temp_df[col].duplicated(), col] = ''
    return temp_df

df = get_freqs(df, ['qid1', 'qid2'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     qid1    qid2  qid1_freq  qid2_freq
0      23      24          1          1
1      25      26          1          1
2      27      28          1          1
3  318830  318831          1          6
4  359558                  1          6
5  384105                  1          6
6  413505                  1          6
7  451953                  1          6
8  530151                  1          6
9  495894    4394          1          1
```

---

If I wanted to do more of what you're doing...

Given:

```
   id  qid1  qid2                       question1                question2  is_duplicate
0   0     1     2            Why is the sky blue?  Why isn't the sky blue?             0
1   1     3     4  Why is the sky blue and green?  Why isn't the sky pink?             0
2   2     5     6                   Where are we?     Moon landing a hoax?             0
3   3     7     8                      Am I real?    Chickens aren't real.             0
4   4     9    10     If this Fake, surely it is?     Oops I did it again.             0
```

Doing:

```
def do_stuff(df):
    t_df = df.copy()
    quids = [x for x in t_df.columns if 'qid' in x]
    questions = [x for x in t_df.columns if 'question' in x]
    for col in quids:
            t_df['freq_' + col] = t_df.groupby(col)[col].transform('count')
            t_df.loc[t_df[col].duplicated(), col] = ''
    for i, col in enumerate(questions):
            t_df[f'q{i+1}_len'] = t_df[col].str.len()
            t_df[f'q{i+1}_no_words'] = t_df[col].str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: len(x))
    return t_df

df = do_stuff(df)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id qid1 qid2                       question1                question2  is_duplicate  freq_qid1  freq_qid2  q1_len  q1_n_words  q2_len  q2_n_words
0   0    1    2            Why is the sky blue?  Why isn't the sky blue?             0          1          1      20           5      23           5
1   1    3    4  Why is the sky blue and green?  Why isn't the sky pink?             0          1          1      30           7      23           5
2   2    5    6                   Where are we?     Moon landing a hoax?             0          1          1      13           3      20           4
3   3    7    8                      Am I real?    Chickens aren't real.             0          1          1      10           3      21           3
4   4    9   10     If this Fake, surely it is?     Oops I did it again.             0          1          1      27           6      20           5
```

Comment: in the above def get_freqs(df, cols), why you used  temp_df = df.copy(). i couldnt understand it and thanks for the elaborated solution. @BeRT2me.

Comment: It's mostly left over from testing, because if you modify a DataFrame inside of a function, it also modifies it outside of the function. Making a copy and then modifying the copy protects changes from happening except in a controlled manner.

Comment: just one more question, how should I add or subtract frequencies of two columns derived in get_freq function. thanks @BeRT2me